# Random sized nested lists and algorithms

Tags: python

I have a program that generates random number of nested lists and each list has random number of elements in these lists.

All the data is either CIDR IP ranges or IP ranges. I need to convert these IP ranges + CIDR ranges to number of IP address available to these ranges. However I need these number of IP addresses to be in the same nested list structure.

I have the algorithm to convert the IP ranges and CIDR ranges but I cannot figure out how to create a new list with the same nest list structure with the random sizes.

Example of required output: [ip = ip range]
nested list: [ip1, ip2, ip3], [ip4, ip5, ip6], [ip7, ip8, ip9]

Example of Final output:
nested list: [777, 52, 21], [11, 7, 2], [888, 13, 5]

When I put my algorithm into a loop to calculate the IP ranges into number of IP address, I lose the nested loop structure format.

The reason I need it in the same nested loop structure is that I need to create a spreadsheet file with xslxwriter and the original nested lists has the correct amount of lists to put into the spreadsheet file.

Remember these nested loops are random, change frequently day to day.

Here is an example of my code to solve my problem, ill use ip_list2 for the program instead of the variable nested_list1 or nested_list2. The final code will be different.

Code example:

```
from netaddr import *
import re

def IPRange2(IPRange):
    regex = r'(\b25[0-5]|\b2[0-4][0-9]|\b[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}.(\b25[0-5]|\b2[0-4][0-9]|\b[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}'
    newips = " "
    ip1 = 0
    ip2 = 0

    IPRange = str(IPRange)

    if re.match(regex, IPRange):
        newips = IPRange.split('-', 1)
        ip1 = newips[0]
        ip2 = newips[1]
    else:
        print("Regular expression did not match the IP range.")

    def ip_to_int(ip):
        val = 0
        ip = str(ip)
        for i, s in enumerate(ip.split('.')):
            val += int(s) * 256 ** (3 - i)
        return val

    def int_to_ip(val):
        octets = []
        for i in range(4):
            octets.append(str(val % 256))
            val = val >> 8
        return '.'.join(reversed(octets))

    def findIPs(start, end):
        for i in range(ip_to_int(start), ip_to_int(end) + 1):
            yield int_to_ip(i)

    totalip = len(list(findIPs(ip1, ip2)))

    return totalip



ipRangeRegex = r'(\b25[0-5]|\b2[0-4][0-9]|\b[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}.(\b25[0-5]|\b2[0-4][0-9]|\b[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}'
iprange = []


ipCidrRegex = r'^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}($|/(16|24))$'
ipCidrRegex2 = r'^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$'

ip_list = ["10.0.14.80/29", "10.56.0.0/29", "10.56.9.0/24", "10.56.68.0/23", "10.56.86.0/23", "10.56.221.0/24", "10.142.0.0/16"] #CIDR only
ip_list2 = ["10.0.14.80/29", "10.56.0.0/29", "10.56.9.0/24", "10.56.68.0/23", "10.56.86.0/23", "10.56.221.0/24", "10.142.0.0/16", "10.56.39.0-10.56.40.253"] #CIDR and IP Range

nested_list1 = [['10.0.14.80/29', '10.56.0.0/29', '10.0.10.16/29'], ['10.0.10.16/29', '10.2.8.0/24'], ['62.118.176.1-68.118.191.254', '209.250.15.1-214.250.15.254'], ['10.0.14.88/29', '10.141.128.0/18']]
nested_list2 = [['10.0.14.80/29', '10.56.0.0/29'], ['10.0.10.16/29', '10.2.8.0/24'], ['63.118.176.1-63.118.191.252', '214.220.15.1-218.210.15.254'], ['10.0.14.88/29', '10.141.128.0/18']]

z = 0
q = 0

calculated_list = []

for test2 in ip_list2: #regular list
#for test2 in nested_list1: #nested list wont work
    test2 = str(test2)
    if re.search(ipRangeRegex, test2): #testing for IP range
        print("IP range match found")
        ipcountedrange = IPRange2(test2)
        print(f"IP Range: {test2}, number of hosts: {ipcountedrange} \n")
        q = q + 1
        #calculated_list.append(ipcountedrange) #THIS JUST WONT WORK TO THE RANDOM NESTED LIST REQUIREMENTS

    if re.search(ipCidrRegex2, test2):
        print("IP CIDR match found")
        ip = IPNetwork(test2)
        ip_count = ip.size
        print(f"IP CIDR: {test2}, number of hosts: {ip_count} \n")
        #calculated_list.append(ip_count) #THIS JUST WONT WORK TO THE RANDOM NESTED LIST REQUIREMENTS
        z = z + 1

print(f"Found IP CIDR matches: {z} times, and IP Ranges {q} times")
print("End of Program")
```

Comment: Please, can you post a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? In particular one without using netaddr, which is not a default python module  and clearly not necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: Also, edit the desired output: when you say "nested list: [777, 52, 21], [11, 7, 2], [888, 13, 5]", do you mean `[[777, 52, 21], [11, 7, 2], [888, 13, 5]]`?

Comment: Ignatius, sorry yes that is what I mean, just was trying to describe the problem as fast as I could, not knowing if anyone would answer.